# Remove class of parents after ajax calls

Tags: css, jquery, javascript

Alright all you jquery pros out there. This problem feels pretty hairy to me. I will do my best to give as much information as I can so that it is clear.

I have a hierarchical structure of divs. They are set up such that there are three layers. Each layer has a refresh button on it. When I click the top layer's refresh button, then all three layers' refresh buttons start spinning. That is as expected.

The goal is that when the bottom layer's refresh image stops spinning (meaning that the ajax call returned and that layer was updated), I want the images in the parent layers to stop spinning as well.

Here is what is happening in the code:

```
function refresh(layer){
  switch(layer){
  case 'bottom layer':
      Make ajax call for self and then update page
      Remove class rotate (which makes the image rotate)
  case 'middle layer':
      For each middle layer, call refresh with the middle layer's 'bottom layer' children
  case 'top layer':
      for each top layer, call refresh with 'middle layer' children
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I cannot tell the parents to remove class rotate themselves because then it is removed before the ajax call on the child is done. I don't want the class on the parents removed until the child is done with the ajax call.

Also, I wasn't completely honest when I said that there are three layers because really the function is being called when an image is clicked on and that image is in a div and that div is in the div of the middle layer header, etc. I can figure out how to navigate the DOM to get to the parents, I just want some psuedo code and explanation as to how to not remove class rotate from the parents until all children are done updating.
**Finish EDIT**

I sure hope this makes sense. I can't put the actual code because it is proprietary and rather lengthy; We don't like walls of code.

How do I tell the bottom layer to remove the class 'rotate' from its parents when all of the bottom layers are done updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a function that takes the class off for me. The function found the parent of the child div and from there had access to all of its children images. In this way, the parent could remove the rotate class from itself and all of its children.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i don't understand your queston but with this :

```
var divMiddleLayer = ("divBottomLayer").parent();
var divTopLayer = ("divMiddleLayer").parent();
divMiddleLayer.removeClass("rotate");
divTopLayer.removeClass("rotate");
```

Comment: I made an edit to my question. I wasn't clear enough at first. I know how to remove classes, I just don't want the classes on the parents removed until the children are done updating. And that is hard with ajax calls, ya know?

Comment: Are you swedish? Grymt om du är. Jag bodde i Sverige i ett tag.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you get on your way.

You can use jQuery.when() to only do something when multiple ajax requests are finished.

```
$.when($.ajax({
      url: yoururl,
      type: "POST"
     }), $.ajax({
      url: yoururl,
      type: "POST"
     }), $.ajax({
      url: yoururl,
      type: "POST"
     }), $.ajax({
      url: yoururl,
      type: "POST"
     })).done( function() {
        //do your parent remove
     });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Wow. That is much less hairy than I thought. I believe that this is what I need!